# Using GraniteDS with a Java client

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, graniteds

Has anyone used GraniteDS successfully with a plain Java client and lazy-loading (a real Java client or a Java server application calling another server)?

Is any special client-side initialization needed? (the docs say nothing about this so we assumed no need, simply took the example code)

Based on the docs (3.0.M2), we have created a Spring backend and a Java client which works for simple POJOs but fails when Hibernate-loaded POJOs would need to be returned (both the RemoteService and Tide versions fail with the same deserialization exceptions).

Currently, we don't have a client-side GraniteDS configuration file, only this code:

```
String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/WebApp_Development_Client_Maven/";
URI uri = new URI(baseURL + "graniteamf/amf.txt");

Transport tr = new ApacheAsyncTransport();
tr.start();
AMFRemotingChannel ch = new AMFRemotingChannel(tr, "graniteamf", uri);

RemoteService srv = new RemoteService(ch, "userService");
List users = (List)srv.newInvocation("listUsers").invoke().get().getData();
```

The de-serialization exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The ActionScript3 class bound to limes.core.model.security.User (ie: [RemoteClass(alias="limes.core.model.security.User")]) implements flash.utils.IExternalizable but this Java class neither implements java.io.Externalizable nor is in the scope of a configured externalizer (please fix your granite-config.xml)
    at org.granite.messaging.amf.io.AMF3Deserializer.readAMF3Object(AMF3Deserializer.java:500)
    at org.granite.messaging.amf.io.AMF3Deserializer.readObject(AMF3Deserializer.java:130)
    at org.granite.messaging.amf.io.AMF3Deserializer.readObject(AMF3Deserializer.java:92)
    ... 36 more
```

Context:

We have a client-server Java/Swing application that was originally designed for intranet use (utilizes Hibernate 3 as the ORM). It also works through the internet but the PostgreSQL database connection very often breaks which makes the client unreliable (random freezes due to lost/broken db connection). This seems to be impossible to solve correctly (the easy measures like manual re-connection is already implemented)

We need to deploy the app over the internet and since the complex logic is already refactored into service classes we would like to leave the GUI mostly unchanged and remote the service classes. We are moving the persistence layer and the service classes into a Spring backend and would like to use GraniteDS because transparent lazy-loading is heavily utilized in the application so it would be very hard to replace it with DTO usage and/or Initializers.

I have not found plain-Java client examples, only a JavaFX example app which is so heavily tied to JavaFX that it seems very hard to transform into a plain-Java client (even trying it out is slightly problematic on Linux since it has no Webstart config included).

Comment: The deserialization exception has been solved, it was caused by having Hibernate3 in the classpath of the client instead of Hibernate4 and GraniteDS eating the real close of the exception. After some debugging of the GraniteDS client the real cause was found and the problem rectified. I don't cause the question because lazy-loading doesn't work yet and that may need some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that lazy-loading doesn't work in this version of GraniteDS (3.0.0.M2) with the plain-Java client.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/graniteds/KDWNY31lG0I

In theory, it works in the JavaFX environment but it was implemented in a way that plain-Java clients cannot use transparent lazy loading.

Also, GraniteDS doesn't support lazy-loading on single entities, only on collections which makes it unsuitable for projects using such relations. Personally, I think this is a glaring omission especially since they often refer to their lazy-loading support as "full".

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't say anything about the lazy-loading limitations  and also fails to make the distinction between the capabilities of GraniteDS with JavaFX and plain Java.